# SQL oracle using date object

Tags: sql, date, compare

I am looking to compare two dates having the following format : 'YYYYMMDD'. 
I tried to compare them using the operators <>=, but it wasn't very accurate.

Do you know how can I use date objects to do this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean it wasn't very accurate? What was your expected and actual result?

Answer (score 0):

You should try converting both dates to timestamps using [TO_TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm#i999843), then they should be safe to compare. Alternatively, look at [TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions194.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is used in converting it to YYYYMMDD format.

```
 To_Date(Sysdate,'YYYYMMDD');
```

After converting both u can compare with string compare or operators <>=